# Using Generics with GraphTypes

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and trying to create a GraphType for a Generic class.

Here are my data objects:

```
public class UserInfo
{
        public string UserAlias { get; set; }
        public List<int> Subs { get; set; }
        public List<int> Biz { get; set; }
}



 public class EntityCollection<T>
 {
        public bool MoreRecords { get; set; }
        public string ContinuationToken { get; set; }
        public IList<T> Results { get; set; }
 }
```

Here are my GraphTypes:

```
public class UserInfoGraphType : ObjectGraphType<UserInfo>
    {
        public UserInfoGraphType()
        {
            Field(x => x.UserAlias);
            Field<ListGraphType<IntGraphType>>("biz", resolve: context=>context.Source.Biz);
            Field<ListGraphType<IntGraphType>>("subs", resolve: context => context.Source.Subs);

        }
    }

 public class EntityCollectionType<T>:  ObjectGraphType<EntityCollection<T>> where T: IObjectGraphType
    {
        public EntityCollectionType()
        {
            Field(x => x.MoreRecords);
            Field(x => x.ContinuationToken);
            Field<ListGraphType<T>>("Results");
        }
    }
```

Here is my query:

```
public Queries(IRepository UserInfoRepository)
    {
         Field<EntityCollectionType>("userinfo",
         arguments: new QueryArguments { new QueryArgument { Name="userAlias"} },
         resolve: context => {
                  return new EntityCollection<UserInfo>();
         }

    );
    }
```

> Firing the "userinfo" query gives me the following error: 
>   {GraphQL.ExecutionError: Expected value of type 
>   "SMDPDaaS.GraphTypes.EntityCollectionType1[SMDPDaaS.GraphTypes.UserInfoGraphType]"
>   for "EntityCollectionType1" but got: 
>   SMDPDaaS.ModelEntity.EntityCollection1[SMDPDaaS.ModelEntity.UserInfo].
>   at 
>   GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ValidateNodeResult(ExecutionContext
>   context, ExecutionNode node) at 
>   GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteNodeAsync(ExecutionContext 
>   context, ExecutionNode node)} How do I make the graphql engine map 
>   SMDPDaaS.ModelEntity.EntityCollection1[SMDPDaaS.ModelEntity.UserInfo] 
>   to
>   SMDPDaaS.GraphTypes.EntityCollectionType`1[SMDPDaaS.GraphTypes.UserInfoGraphType]?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well. Here is how I solved it.

```
public class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet<T>
{
  public T[] Results { get; set; }
  public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
}

public class BookType : ObjectGraphType<Book>
{
  public BookType()
  {
    Field(b => b.Id);
    Field(b => b.Title);
  }
}

public class ResultSetType<T, TType> : ObjectGraphType<ResultSet<T>>
  where TType : IGraphType
{
  public ResultSetType()
  {
    Name = $"{typeof(TType).Name}ResultSet";
    Field<ListGraphType<TType>>("results");
    Field<IntGraphType>("totalResultsCount");
  }
}
```

This can now be used as a field in a query as follows:

```
Field<ResultSetType<Book, BookType>>(
                "books",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "pageIndex" }, new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "pageSize" }),
                resolve: ctx => booksRepository.ReadBooks(ctx.GetArgument<int>("pageIndex"), ctx.GetArgument<int>("pageSize"))
            );
```

My query allows for paging where a user(or UI) could specify how many results they want to get at once as well as which page they want to view, so it is passing in two arguments, but the part that would be of interest to you would be `Field<ResultSetType<Book, BookType>>("books");`